# C# executing cmd command not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Can anybody suggest why the following code not returning system date?

```
 ProcessStartInfo cmdInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "net time \\192.168.221.1");
            cmdInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            cmdInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            cmdInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            cmdInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            Process cmd = new Process();
            cmd.StartInfo = cmdInfo;
            var output = new StringBuilder();
            var error = new StringBuilder();

            cmd.OutputDataReceived += (o, e) => output.Append(e.Data);
            cmd.ErrorDataReceived += (o, e) => error.Append(e.Data);

            cmd.Start();
            cmd.BeginOutputReadLine();
            cmd.BeginErrorReadLine();
            cmd.WaitForExit();
            cmd.Close();
            var s = output;
            var d = error;
```

Output is

```
{Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.D:\TEST\TEST\bin\Debug>}
```

Comment: Set `CreateNoWindow` to `false` and see the actual output on the cmd window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this

```
ProcessStartInfo cmdInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C net time \\\\192.168.221.1");
```

You need to add the /C switch to catch the output of running command inside the CMD shell.
Also the backslash should be doubled or use the string Verbatim prefix `@`

Comment: Execute the command and exits. Without you catch only the copyright notice and then the shell exits (Type in command window `CMD /?`)